# Where can I store my webserver URLs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, global-variables

I hard code all URLs in my mobile app which I know is not a good idea. For example, if I were to ever need to move domain names I'd need to rename all URLs within the app from www.oldname.com to www.newname.com on each and every page.

I'm not sure where and how to store them so that I can modify this information on a single page and have it automatically changed across all pages.

In PHP I'd create a single file with variables that'd I'd include in all pages. I'm not sure how this is done in objective-c however. How do you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a constants file and include that in all other file where the URL is listed.

Create a file, e.g. constants.h where you put all your contstants.
In constants.h you could put something like this:

```
#define kApiBaseUrl @"https://myapi.mydomain.com"
```

And in your other files you acces it like this example:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kApiBaseUrl];
```

Probably this is like what you did use to do in PHP.
You can also set predefined URL's in the PLIST of your app but this is probably easier.

Answer (score 2):

similar to edwardmp's response, you can also create a Constants.h file and define some static constant strings.

```
static NSString *const kSiteRootURL = @"http://www.someurl.com";
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the folder "Supporting Files" inside your project you should have a file named "nameOfYourApp-Prefix.pch" then you can define the root URL for exemple

```
#define ROOT_URL    @"yourwebsite.com"
```

and you can access ROOT_URL from anywhere in your project

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your URLs in a property list file (File => New file => Property ...). You will have something like "config.plist". Similar with other property file, it is key => value file where the value can be a string, an arrays, etc.

Use NSBundle to load the file in your app, like

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"config" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *config = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

This will give a benefit where you don't have to re-compile again your codes whenever you make any change on the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a NSString to your .pch file to be included in all of modules.